# Mongoose findOne in stream callback not executed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I execute a findOne query to a collection that is different than that of the surrounding stream, it doesn't really execute the callback (does 1 or 2).  Here is my code:

schema.js:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var AutocompleteSchema = new Schema({
  nGram: String,
  locations: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Location' }]  
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Autocomplete', AutocompleteSchema);
```

ingest.js:

```
var Autocomplete = require('./schema');
var nGramAPI = require('ngram');
var cache = [];
function storeNGram(input, location) {
    if(cache.indexOf(input) === -1) {
        cache.push(input);
        Autocomplete
        .findOne({ nGram: input })
        .populate('locations')
        .exec(function (err, nGram) {
        console.log(nGram);
            if(!nGram) {
                var newAutocomplete = {
                    nGram: input,
                    locations: [location._id]
                };
                Autocomplete.create(newAutocomplete, function(err, created) {
                    cache.splice(cache.indexOf(input), 1);
                });
            }
            else {
                nGram.locations.push(location._id);
                sortLocations(nGram);
                location.save(function(err, saved){
                    cache.splice(cache.indexOf(input), 1);
                });
            }
        }); 
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            storeNGram(input, location);
        }, 100);
    }
}

exports.ingest = function() {
    console.log("Building nGrams");
    var stream = Location.find().stream();
    stream.on('data', function (location) {
        var length = location.dispName.length > 20 ? 20 : location.dispName.length;
        for(var i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
            _.each(nGramAPI(i)(location.dispName), function(nGram) {
                storeNGram(nGram, location);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

When I execute the Autocomplete.findOne on its own outside of the stream it queries properly, but when inside it fails. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the callback get passed the `err` argument? Could you log that and not ignore it? Where is the model variable `Autocomplete` actually defined? Your code only assigns `module.exports` so something is missing.

Comment: _.each(nGram(i)(location.dispName) should be  _.each(nGram[i][location.dispName] but I don't know that that's your problem

Comment: @BrianNoah I just realized this could have a lot to do with it, i am using a third party library called nGram and i have labeled it the same as function(nGram), I will update this tonight and see if that changes anything.

Comment: That didn't seem to fix it.